# How can I run a powershell script as a background task without displaying a window?

Tags: powershell, command-line, background

I'm working on creating a script that will fire off performance counters and store them in a .csv file, rolling over when the file gets too big. Running the script from a powershell prompt or the ISE (I'm running v.2/win server 2008) works just fine, and the files are running correctly.

However, when I try to execute the command using the following cmd prompt line (even trying the /k switch on cmd), the command prompt closes immediately and the file is not getting run.

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden {iis_test.ps1}
```

I've also tried the following, and although I see Powershell doesn't stop (I monitor it via task manager, looking for Powershell.exe to show up), I'm not seeing the file being created.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -windowstyle hidden {iis_test.ps1}
```

Nor am I seeing any errors being caught in any of the likely places (event viewer, the command prompt window itself).

Any ideas? Ultimately, my goal is to have a vb winforms thing call these script files, and naturally I thought figuring out the command prompt command would be helpful. **Note** that it is very important that this script be portable, and run on any Windows 2008 Server system (so I need to stay away from third party entities that would require further installation).

**EDIT:** I needed to use the -file argument to specify a file to run.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try this from a DOS/CMD shell:

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file C:\iis_test.ps1
```

Comment: this still displays a window, although briefly upon starting

Comment: hmm I use `pwsh -windowstyle hidden C:\script.ps1` and it still works. Any idea?

Comment: Important: "[When the value of File is a file path, File must be the last parameter in the command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-file----filepath-args)"

Answer (score 12):

```
Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file C:\iis_test.ps1
```

But when you run this command, a CMD window will appear.
However, you can use VBscript instead

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "CMD /C START /B " & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%") & "\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file " & "YourScript.ps1", 0, False
Set objShell = Nothing
```