# How to make a python file run in the background when minimized?

Tags: python, windows, background-process

I made a Python program that I do NOT want to turn into .exe or anything else.
However since the program needs python.exe to run, it runs python.exe openly.
I want to know if I can add a piece of code to the program I made so that it runs in the background.
BTW, I do not want to run through cmd.I want it to be a background process automatically.
Basically, I want to add some code into my program so that as soon as it is clicked upon, it runs in background.

Comment: Check [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKl7scEW90c), it might help.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is directly possible.  I don't think you're going to find a way of having a Python script put the Python interpreter that is running it into the background.  How about having a shell script that goes with it?  This script could launch Python in the background and then exit.  I don't know Windows, but I assume that you can create a shell script that you can click on as easily as you can a Python script directly. - If you were on Mac or Linux, I'd be able tell you exactly how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What resources have you found that seem plausible? Those are critical aspects of [the SO how-to-ask docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which would help us here. Lots and lots of potential ways to achieve what you're requesting. Additionally, maybe [these SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303561/5369706) can help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to do this easily: I just renamed my file.py into file.pyw
Now, it runs without a console. Basically I typed this in the cmd:
`ren file.py file.pyw`