# How to run windows powershell script in background

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-processing

How to run a powershell script in background.Looking for something equivalent to & in unix
The script should run even after i signout from the windows machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a powershell script in the background once per minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071496/run-a-powershell-script-in-the-background-once-per-minute) or [How can I run a powershell script as a background task without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303150/1701026)

Comment: When you log off, all your processes are terminated. Look at scheduled tasks or services for running processes continuously.